# Unable to make html/java script form function correctly

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm struggling with a solution for this. I have the first block of code, which I want to use for css formatting/look feel etc.

```
<div class="login-form">
        <!-- Start Error box -->
        <div class="alert alert-danger hide">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> &times;</button>
            <h4>Error!</h4>
            Your Error Message goes here
        </div> <!-- End Error box -->
        <form action="#" method="get"  >
            <input type="text" placeholder="User name" class="input-field" required/> 
            <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" class="input-field" required/> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login">Login</button> 
        </form> 
    </div>
```

Then I have this separate code that uses a script to submit the user info once entered. I want to move the actions that this script performs onto the above code. Therefore having the look and feel of the first block of code and the actions of the second.

I'm learning at the moment, so it seems logical to try and use example code that exists as a starting point. I'm not able to find any help on goofle that direcly helps resolve this question.

I think if I could work out if I can wrap the script around the top block I could get it from there, just need some direction.

```
<div class="container" id="login-block">
    <script type="text/template" id="login-template">
      <header id="header"></header>
      <div class="login">
        <form class="login-form">

          <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
          <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" />
          <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button>Log In</button>
        </form>
</script>
```

Comment: why is your html code inside the script tag, I think that is not what you want :)

Comment: @MatthiasLaug You can place html within a script tag when following HTML 5 principles, as I understand. It allows this to insert data into a document – the type must just not be one that gets it interpreted as scripting language. (Also it should be a valid MIME type.)

Comment: mh ok my bad, never used it that way, but I am not getting what you are trying to archive...

Comment: Me too, not clear on goal. Do you want to put the script in the HTML just for an exercise or programming style? I'd be inclined to stick with the traditional "load the DOM" then "do something with it".

Comment: Perhaps I can explain better like this. this version is the form and formatting I'd like to achieve http://kudosoo.com/work.html and this version http://kudosoo.com/messy.html actually has the functions I want the form to do when the user enters details. I need to get the functions working with the correctly styles form. Does that help? @TimSPQR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted to achieve. Works now, only taken 3 hours to work it out ;-/

```
<div class="container" id="login-block todoapp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="page-icon-shadow animated bounceInDown" > </div>
            <div class="login-box clearfix animated flipInY" id="login-block">
                <div class="page-icon animated bounceInDown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="login-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/login-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" /></a>
                </div> 
                <hr />
                <div class="login-form content">
                    <!-- Start Error box -->
                    <div class="alert alert-danger hide">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-login" data-dismiss="alert"> &times;</button>
                        <h4>Error!</h4>
                        Your Error Message goes here
                    </div></div> <!-- End Error box -->


                    <script type="text/template" id="login-template">
                    <header id="header"></header>
                    <div class="login">
                    <form class="login-form">

                    <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
                    <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <button>Log In</button>
                    </form>
                    </script>



                    <div class="login-links"> 
                        <a href="forgot-password.html">
                            Forgot password?
                        </a>
                        <br />
                        <a href="sign-up.html">
                            Don't have an account? <strong>Sign Up</strong>
                        </a>
                    </div>              
                </div>                      
            </div>

        </div> </div>
```